# Method validation Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I am using Spring Boot + Hibernate + Kotlin.

What I am trying to do is the following:

I have a Question object with a questionTime and an answerTime (see code below). I want to constraint that the answerTime is always longer than or equal to the questionTime. I want this constrainted at the database level. How can I do this? The only thing I would want is database independent.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
class Question(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
        var id: Long,
        @Column(name = "question_time")
        @ColumnDefault(value = "-1")
        var questionTime: Int = -1,
        @Column(name = "answer_time")
        @ColumnDefault(value = "-1")
        var answerTime: Int = -1


)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need support db constraints for entity you can use `@Check` annotation.

```
    @Check("name_db_constraint")
    @Column(name = "answer_time")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "-1")
    var answerTime: Int = -1
```

If you need to have same constraint from server side use Validation framework, you can create constraint with extension

Comment: Hmm I forgot to mention that I wanted it being database independent. I will add it. Else this would be a valid answer. Thank you.

Comment: hibernate doen't support create custom db constraints with ddl - auto - mode